# Handling Multiple Timers in Windows Program

Tags: c++, windows, timer

I am writing a C/C++ based windows network application/game in MSVS 2013.  On one end is my server which accepts multiple clients via TCP connections.  For each client that connects, the server will start sending questions that the client will need to answer in a certain amount of time.  To handle sending questions and timing a response, I create a standard windows timer (WM_TIMER) for each client.  Therefore, as the number of clients increase, so do the number of timers I need to create.

My question is whether this is the best approach.  I am looking for a method with a low overhead and that will not greatly affect my application's performance or the client's experience when multiple users connect.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of creating timers, create a thread for each clients and use events (see `CreateEvent` and `SetEvent` functions on MSDN)

Comment: You only ever need *one* timer to time an arbitrary number of intervals.  You just have to set it to tick for the next one that's due.  Once it does, iterate the all connections that should be timed out.  Rinse and repeat.